# Adding onFocus to redux form field

Tags: redux-form

I am using redux form and I want to add my own **onFocus** (or onChange, onBlur etc) event handler to my Field component.

Will this have any side effects with the Field component?

```
<Field
  name="MyInputField"
  component={LabeledInputField}
  onFocus=()=>alert('I want to add my own focus event here')
/>
```

I am just thinking because would this override the internal onFocus event handler in redux form? Or are the handlers somehow chained?